# AWS Glue job write to s3 in parquet format error with Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I've been creting pyspark jobs and I keep getting one similar and intermittently error (is more like random):

```
An error occurred while calling o129.parquet. Not Found 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; 
Request ID: D2FA355F92AF8F05; S3 Extended Request ID: 1/fWdf1DurwPDP40HDGARlMRO/7lKzFDJ4g7DbUnM04wUvG89CG9w5T+u4UxapkWp20MfQfdjsE=)
```

I'm not even reading from s3, what I'm actually doing is:
`df.coalesce(100).write.partitionBy("mth").mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://"+bucket+"/"+path+"/out")`

So I change the `coalesce` partition, but I'm not wure what else should I do to mitigate this error and make my jobs more stable.

Comment: Have you verified the s3 permissions of role used to write to this bucket?

Comment: Yes, access is there. Error does not happen all the time, is like random, one time it works and write the output and sometimes it just fail with this error.

Comment: Best thing is to reach out to AWS support with request Id and extended request Id from your error trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for reading the file from s3 using glue

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options( connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": "s3/path"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
```

for writing file to s3 using glue

```
output = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = df, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3/path"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "output")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this different way to write to S3, it was implemented before and I don't know if this way will solve the issue I'm having.
What I have to add is the following code: 
```dynamic_frame_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df,glueContext, "nested")```

Comment: This solved the first run, let me run it a couple more and I'll let you know if this entirely solve the issue of writing to s3. Thanks Jay!

Comment: Cool no problem keep it up